# HTML5 download link a[download] bypasses service-worker

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, download, service-worker

**It seems to me that HTML5 download links bypasses any registered Service-Worker? Is this intended design?**

```
<a href="/assets/images/i_am_cached_by_service_worker.png" download>link</a>
```

Both in Chrome v.62 and in Firefox v.57 this seems to be the case.

In Firefox it says it picked the .png file from the browser cache (304, not changed) which lies beyond the service-worker layer (note: all files were served with no-cache originally).

In Chrome the download activity doesn't even show in the Network tab at all.

Only if I go to chrome://net-internals/#events do I see it and there it never calls i.e. "SERVICE_WORKER_START_REQUEST" which seemingly all other network activities does. It just bypasses the Service-Worker layer and goes straight to the server.

---

**Note:** If I make a traditional download link:

`<a href="/sw/files/unique_file_only_in_indexeddb.png" target="_blank">link</a>`

then it will be handled by Service-Worker just fine (assuming registered Service-Worker scope is at URL root).

**2nd. Note:** In my case the Service-Worker scope is NOT at root (*/region/shop*) and I use a workaround where I have every attachment links be within that same scope, ensuring it's handled by the Service-Worker, but from inside the Server-Worker itself I can re-direct that request to wherever suits me (outside of scope).
Hash '#' breaks browser download behavior however (when using just a normal href link or target="_blank") and is excluded from url in link element. Registered Service-Worker scope should therefor not include '#' char for SPA's. This is all a workaround however and doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: This issue is still valid in 2021

Comment: Still a problem in 2023. The related Chromium issue from 2015 is still open: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468227